# Hiding empty columns in Gridview using DataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using the following to hide empty columns with the DataBound event in my Gridview. It works great for BoundField columns but hides other types such as TemplateFields and HyperLinkFields even when there is data present.

```
protected void MyTable_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Boolean hasData = false;
   for (int col = 0; col < MyTable.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; col++)
   {
      for (int row = 0; row < MyTable.Rows.Count; row++)
      {
         if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyTable.Rows[row].Cells[col].Text)
                        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(MyTable.Rows[row].Cells[col].Text).Trim()))
         {
            hasData = true;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (!hasData)
      {
         MyTable.HeaderRow.Cells[col].Visible = false;
         for(int hiddenrows = 0; hiddenrows < MyTable.Rows.Count; hiddenrows++)
         {
            MyTable.Rows[hiddenrows].Cells[col].Visible = false;
         }
      }
      hasData = false;
   }
}
```

How can I prevent these fields from being hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check column type:

```
protected void MyTable_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boolean hasData = false;
    for (int col = 0; col < MyTable.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; col++)
    {
        if (MyTable.Columns[col] is HyperLinkField || MyTable.Columns[col] is TemplateField)
        {
            continue;
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < MyTable.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyTable.Rows[row].Cells[col].Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(MyTable.Rows[row].Cells[col].Text).Trim()))
            {
                hasData = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    if (!hasData)
    {
        MyTable.HeaderRow.Cells[col].Visible = false;
        for(int hiddenrows = 0; hiddenrows < MyTable.Rows.Count; hiddenrows++)
        {
            MyTable.Rows[hiddenrows].Cells[col].Visible = false;
        }
    }

        hasData = false;
    }
}
```